# Clickhouse: Want to extract data from Array(Tupple) column in Clickhouse

Tags: mysql, sql, clickhouse, clickhouse-client, clickhouse-go

Query used to create the table:

`CREATE TABLE default.ntest2(job_name String, list_data Array(Tuple(s UInt64, e UInt64, name String))) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY (job_name) SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;`

Table Data:

| job_name | list_data.s | list_data.e | list_data.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| job1 | [19,22] | [38,92] | ['test1','test2'] |
| job2 | [28,63] | [49,87] | ['test3''test4'] |

Expected Output:

| job_name | list_data.s | list_data.e | list_data.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| job1 | 19 | 38 | 'test1' |
| job1 | 22 | 92 | 'test2' |
| job2 | 28 | 49 | 'test3' |
| job2 | 63 | 87 | 'test4' |

How can I achieve this with less query time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARRAY JOIN https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/

```sql
SELECT
    job_name,
    `list_data.s`,
    `list_data.e`,
    `list_data.name`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c1 AS job_name,
        c2 AS list_data
    FROM values(('job1', ([19, 22], [38, 92], ['test1', 'test2'])), ('job2', ([28, 63], [49, 87], ['test3', 'test4'])))
) AS T
ARRAY JOIN
    list_data.1 AS `list_data.s`,
    list_data.2 AS `list_data.e`,
    list_data.3 AS `list_data.name`

┌─job_name─┬─list_data.s─┬─list_data.e─┬─list_data.name─┐
│ job1     │          19 │          38 │ test1          │
│ job1     │          22 │          92 │ test2          │
│ job2     │          28 │          49 │ test3          │
│ job2     │          63 │          87 │ test4          │
└──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┘
```

```sql
SELECT
    job_name,
    list_data.s,
    list_data.e,
    list_data.name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        c1 AS job_name,
        c2 AS `list_data.s`,
        c3 AS `list_data.e`,
        c4 AS `list_data.name`
    FROM values(('job1', [19, 22], [38, 92], ['test1', 'test2']), ('job2', [28, 63], [49, 87], ['test3', 'test4']))
) AS T
ARRAY JOIN
    `list_data.s` AS `list_data.s`,
    `list_data.e` AS `list_data.e`,
    `list_data.name` AS `list_data.name`

┌─job_name─┬─list_data.s─┬─list_data.e─┬─list_data.name─┐
│ job1     │          19 │          38 │ test1          │
│ job1     │          22 │          92 │ test2          │
│ job2     │          28 │          49 │ test3          │
│ job2     │          63 │          87 │ test4          │
└──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks Denny, It's working. 

Just wondering, can we do similar with Array(Nested(s UInt64, e UInt64, name String))) as well?

table will look something like this:
┌─job_name─┬─list_data────────────────────────┐
│ job1     │ [[(1,2,'name1')],[(4,5,'name2')]]     │
│ job2     │ [[(22,33,'name3')],[(44,55,'name4')]] │
│ job5     │ [[(22,33,'name3'),(44,55,'name4')]]   │

Comment: Do you understand Nested is Array already? Basically you are asking about `Array(Array(s UInt64, e UInt64, name String)))`. Provide CREATE TABLE / INSERT, I will provide SELECT.

Comment: All details are mentioned in this question. can you please refer to this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302499/clickhouse-want-to-extract-data-from-arraynested-column-in-clickhouse

Comment: my question remains: Do you understand Nested is Array already?

Comment: yes, a nested data structure is like a table inside a cell. 

Info from the website: "For an INSERT query, you should pass all the component column arrays of a nested data structure separately (as if they were individual column arrays). During insertion, the system checks that they have the same length."
for more information: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/