# Clickhouse: Want to extract data from Array(Nested) column in Clickhouse

Tags: mysql, sql, clickhouse, clickhouse-client, clickhouse-go

Query used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE default.ntest2(
       job_name String, 
       list_data Array(Nested(s UInt64, e UInt64, name String))
   ) 
   ENGINE = MergeTree 
   ORDER BY (job_name) 
   SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

Table Data:

| job_name | list_data |
| --- | --- |
| job1 | [[(1,2,'name1')],[(4,5,'name2')]] |
| job2 | [[(22,33,'name3')],[(44,55,'name4')]] |

Expected Output:

| job_name | list_data.s | list_data.e | list_data.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| job1 | 1 | 2 | 'name1' |
| job1 | 4 | 5 | 'name2' |
| job2 | 22 | 33 | 'name3' |
| job2 | 44 | 55 | 'name4' |

How can I achieve this with less query time?

Comment: Best answer is honestly to not use array columns in the first place. They are inherently slow and error-prone. The expected output is how the data should be created in the first place.

Comment: use clickhouse array join https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/

Answer (score 2):

use clickhouse [array join](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/)

```
SELECT job_name, element.s, element.e, element.name
FROM default.ntest2
ARRAY JOIN element IN list_data
```